# How to prove this is homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

Let $\Bbb R^n \cup\{\infty\} $ be the Alexandroff compactification of  $\Bbb R^n$.

Prove that the function $\phi:\Bbb R^n \cup\{\infty\}\rightarrow\Bbb R^n \cup\{\infty\}, \ $ $\phi(x)=x/|x|^2$ if $ x\neq0,\infty$, $\phi(0)=\infty$ and $\phi(\infty)=0$ is an homeomorphism.

It's clear in case $x\neq0,\infty,$ but I don't know how to prove the continuity in the zero and infinity points. I also know if $\phi$ is continuous, then it's an homeomorphism because $\phi=\phi^{-1}$.

Comment: Recall from the definition of compactification that a set $U$ containing $\infty$ is open if and only if the complement of $U$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Use this to show continuity in the usual way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it remains to check the continuity of the function $\phi$ at points $0$ and $\infty$.

$0$: Since $\phi(0)=\infty$, for each $N>0$ we have to find $\delta>0$ such that $|x|<\delta$ implies $|\phi(x)|>N$.
It suffices to put $\delta=1/N$. Indeed, if $|x|<\delta$ then $|\phi(x)|=1/|x|>N$.

$\infty$: Since $\phi(\infty)=0$, for each $\delta>0$ we have to find $N>0$ such that $|x|>N $ implies $|\phi(x)| <\delta$.
It suffices to put $N=1/\delta$. Indeed, if $|x|>N$ then $|\phi(x)|=1/|x|<\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

In the complex plane let $S^1=\{z: |z|=1\}.$ Let $g:\mathbb R\cup \{\infty \}\to S^1$  where $g(x)=e^{2i\tan^{-1}x}$ for $x\in \mathbb R,$ and $g(\infty)=-1.$ Let $h:S^1\to S^1$ where $h(e^{i\theta})=e^{i(\pi -\theta) }$ for real $\theta .$ Then $g,h,$ and $g^{-1}$ are homeomorphisms, and $f=g^{-1}hg.$

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question as far as I can tell...